Proof about a consistent calculus producing falsehoods
We take the Hilbert calculus H with the additional axiom: $\neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x$. This calculus is consistent, since Hilbert is consistent, and the additional assumption should not cause any issues (we'll just assume that for now). Thus, it holds that $H, \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x \vdash \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x$.
But does $H, \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x \vDash \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x$ also hold?
There are only two possibilities: either $\exists x \forall y: y \notin x$ is true, or $\neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x$ is true.
Does it follow in the first case, that we would have a consistent Hilbert calculus that would trivially be correct due to a false premise/axiom, i.e., yes, $H, \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x \vDash \neg \exists x \forall y: y \notin x$ holds, but the inferred statement would still be false?

Not clear... The additional axiom says that there is no empty set. If there are no further axioms regarding $\in$ there is no reason why the axiom produces an inconsistency
